# jquery to move td below another td

Tags: jquery

From this:

```
<tr>
<td>A</td>
<td>B</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>C</td>
<td>D</td>
</tr>
```

to this:

```
<tr>
<td>A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>B</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>C</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>D</td>
</tr>
```

Ideally I woulnd't want to create a new row for the TD but I don't think there's a way around, is there?

Comment: Are you asking for code to make it happen? Can you post your code so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it

```
$('tr').each(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    self.after('<tr>').next().append( self.find('td:last') );
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/rucsh/

Comment: +1 much better answer than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not another way.

To get a `td` to show up in a new row, you will of course have to make a new row.

To add another row:

```
$('#myTable tr:last').after('<tr><td>' + YOURSTUFF + '</td></tr>');
```

Or if you want to put it after a specific row (moving `B` down):

```
$('#theRow').after('<tr><td>' + YOURSTUFF + '</td></tr>');
```